# ajax success error function doesn't call up in jquery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Hi here is my code..

```
<html>
<head>   
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js">
</script>
</head>  
<body> 
<form id="foo">

    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />

    <input type="submit" value="Send" />

</form>  
<div id ="onsuccess">      
</div>   
<script>  
// variable to hold request
var request;
// bind to the submit event of our form
$("#foo").submit(function(event){   
    var $form = $(this);
    var serializedData = $form.serialize();
    request = $.ajax({
        url: "a.txt",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "text", 
        data: serializedData,
        success: function(){ 
        console.log("yes, its successful");},
        error : function(){console.log("got an error");}
    });
});

</script>
</body> 
</html>
```

i am trying to access a.txt which is in the same directory.But the success and error function never calls up which is not understandable. Firebug net status shows that no calls were made.strange

however if i use

```
request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
        // log a message to the console
        console.log("Hooray, it worked!");
        //$("#success").html(response);
    });
```

it does work.

Comment: I don't understand why posting form to text file?

Comment: i could use get also..but i guess it doesn't make difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add this to submit handler

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Also changing POST to GET works for me on IIS

Comment: yes, it worked...so it means that form was showing its inherent property

Answer (score 0):

Try .done,.fail and .always

The success and error callbacks were [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in jquery 1.8

> Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and
>   jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare
>   your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(),
>   and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: Hi @daniel powell do you want to say that i must use
  request = $.ajax({
        url: "a.txt",
        type: "post",
  dataType: "text", 
        data: serializedData,
  done: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR){ 
  console.log("yes, its successful");},
  
  fail : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){console.log("got an error");}
    });    
but it didn't help me out again nothing happens